# Преобразовать строку с литералом в двумерный массив

Tags: javascript, массивы

В переменной `latilong` хранится строка `"[55,51],[55,50]"`.

Необходимо передать её в качестве массива в метод `ymaps.route`:

```
 ymaps.route([

   latilong;

])
```

Это правильный код? не работает просто.

Comment: @installero, мне кажется ваша правка не к месту. В 1.0 версии API яндекс карт, `ymaps.route` принимал в качестве параметра строку, а не объект, если их документация не врет!?

Comment: В вопросе автор передаёт в эту функцию массив, состоящий из одной строки — так тоже можно было?

Comment: @installero, не знаю, но один из ответов - рекомендация убрать синтаксическую ошибку из точки с запятой - возможно, проблема действительно в этом была.

Comment: В текущей версии Яндекс.Карт вообще нет метода `ymaps.route`, поэтому ценность вопроса как способа передать данные для построения маршрута — сомнительна. В заголовке вопроса, скажем, вообще не было ничего про карты. Впрочем, если есть какой-то гайд по редактированию вопросов — с удовольствием ознакомлюсь.

Answer (score 2):

```
ymaps.route(JSON.parse("[" + latilong + "]"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, в данном случае допустимо использование `eval`:

```
var latilong = "[55,51],[55,50]";
var array = eval("[" + latilong + "]");

console.log(array[0][1]);
→ 51
```

Answer (score 0):

Нет, не правильный. Убери точку с запятой